# I am using Javascript, html, & Canvas to create a game for a project that I am working on, issue is pic overlap and player functionality

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, sprite

The issue that I am having on my project is that after I added my background image when you look through my localhost:3000/index.html the background image layers over my Sprites. but on vscode when I comment out the background It now shows my sprites but they have lost their full functionality that they once had. I need an extra pair of eyes.

I have tried switching the players mobility an changed some names but I still get the same results.

below are the following codes I have worked with and tried to fix:

**(index.js file):**

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 1024
canvas.height = 576

c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

const gravity = 0.7

const background = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    imageSrc: './img/background.jpg'
})
const player = new Fighter({
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
})

const enemy = new Fighter({
    position: {
        x: 400,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    color: 'blue',
    offset: {
        x: -50,
        y: 0
    }
})

console.log(player);

const keys = {
    a: {
        pressed: false
    },
    d: {
        pressed: false
    },

    ArrowRight: {
        pressed: false
    },
    ArrowLeft: {
        pressed: false    }
    }

function rectangularCollision({
    rectangle1,
    rectangle2
}) {
    return (
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x + player.attackBox.width >=
        rectangle2.position.x &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.x <=
        rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.width &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y + player.attackBox.height >=
        rectangle2.position.y &&
        rectangle1.attackBox.position.y <= rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.height
    )
}

function determinewinner({ player, enemy, timerId }) {
    clearTimeout(timerId)
    document.querySelector('#displayText').style.display = 'flex'
    if (player.health === enemy.health) {
        document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'Tie'
    } else if (player.health > enemy.health) {
        document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'player 1 wins'
    } else if (player.health < enemy.health) {
        document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'player 2 wins'
    }
}

let timer = 60
let timerId
function decreaseTimer() {
    if (timer > 0) {
        timerId = setTimeout(decreaseTimer, 1000)
        timer--
        document.querySelector('#timer').innerHTML = timer
    }

    if (timer === 0) {
        determinewinner({ player, enemy, timerId })
    }
}

decreaseTimer()

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.fillStyle = 'black'
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    player.update()
    enemy.update()
    background.update()
    player.velocity.x = 0
    enemy.velocity.x = 0

    // Player Movement
    if (keys.a.pressed && player.lastKey === 'a') {
        player.velocity.x = -5
    } else if (keys.d.pressed && player.lastKey === 'd') {
        player.velocity.x = 5
    }

    // Enemy Movement
    if (keys.ArrowLeft.pressed && enemy.lastKey === 'ArrowLeft') {
        enemy.velocity.x = -5
    } else if (keys.ArrowRight.pressed && enemy.lastKey === 'ArrowRight') {
        enemy.velocity.x = 5
    }

    // detect for collision
    if (
        rectangularCollision({
            rectangle1: player,
            rectangle2: enemy
        }) &&
        player.isAttacking
    ) {
        player.isAttacking = false
        enemy.health -= 20
        document.querySelector['#enemyHealth'].style.width = enemy.health + '%'
    }

    // Game ends based on health
    if (enemy.health <= 0 || player.health <= 0) {
        determinewinner({ player, enemy, timerId })
    }

    if (
        rectangularCollision({
            rectangle1: enemy,
            rectangle2: player
        }) &&
        enemy.isAttacking
    ) {
        enemy.isAttacking = false
        player.health -= 20
        document.querySelector['#playerHealth'].style.width = player.health + '%'
    }
    enemy.isAttacking = false
    console.log('enemy attack successful');
}


animate()

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = true
            player.lastKey = 'd'
            break
        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = true
             player.lastKey = 'a'
            break
        case 'w':
            player.velocity.y = -15
            break
        case ' ':
            player.attack()
            break
        case 'ArrowRight':
            keys.ArrowRight.pressed = true
            enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowRight'
            break
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = true
            enemy.lastKey = 'ArrowLeft'
            break
        case 'ArrowUp':
            enemy.velocity.y = -15
            break
        case 'ArrowDown':
            enemy.isAttacking = true
            break
    }
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'd':
            keys.d.pressed = false
            break
        case 'a':
            keys.a.pressed = false
            break
        case 'w':
            keys.w.pressed = false
            break
    }

    // enemy keys
    switch (event.key) {
        case 'ArrowRight':
            keys.ArrowRight.pressed = false
            break
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            keys.ArrowLeft.pressed = false
            break
        case 'w':
            keys.w.pressed = false
            break
    }
})
```

**(Index.html File):**

```
<head>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- red container div -->
    <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
        <!-- smaller red container div -->
        <div style="
        position: absolute; 
        display: flex; 
        width: 100%; 
        align-items: center;
        padding: 20px;
        ">
            <!-- player health -->
            <div style="position: relative; height: 30px; width: 100%; display: flex; justify-         content: flex-end">
                <div style="background-color: greenyellow; height: 30px; width: 100%;"></div>
                <div id="playerHealth" style="position: absolute; 
                background: red; 
                top: 0; 
                right: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- timer -->
            <div id="timer" style="
                background-color: red; 
                width: 100px; 
                height: 100px; 
                flex-shrink: 0;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            ">
                30
            </div>
            <!-- enemy health -->
            <div style="position: relative; height: 30px; width: 100%">
                <div style="background-color: greenyellow; height: 30px"></div>
                <div id="enemyHealth" style="position: absolute; 
                background: red; 
                top: 0; 
                right: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                left: 0;"></div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div
        id="displayText" 
        style="
        position: absolute; 
        color: white; 
        align-items: center; 
        justify-content: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
        ">
            Tie
        </div>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="js/classes.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS Folder (classes.js file):**

```
class Sprite {
    constructor({ position, imageSrc }) {
        this.position = position
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 150
        this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = imageSrc
    }

    draw() { 
        c.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y)
    }

    update() {
        this.draw()
    }

}

class Fighter {
    constructor({ position, velocity, color = 'red', offset }) {
        this.position = position
        this.velocity = velocity
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 150
        this.lastKey
        this.attackBox = {
            position: {
                x: this.position.x,
                y: this.position.y,
            },
            offset,
            width: 100,
            height: 50
        }
        this.color = color
        this.isAttacking
        this.health = 100
    }

    draw() {
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height)

        //attack box
        if (this.isAttacking) {
            c.fillStyle = 'green'
            c.fillRect(
                this.attackBox.position.x,
                this.attackBox.position.y,
                this.attackBox.width,
                this.attackBox.height
            )
        }
    }

    update() {
        this.draw()
        this.attackBox.position.x = this.position.x + this.attackBox.offset.x
        this.attackBox.position.y = this.position.y

        this.position.x += this.velocity.x
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y

        if (this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y >= canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0
        } else this.velocity.y += gravity
    }


    attack() {
        this.isAttacking = true
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isAttacking = false
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

I literally can't see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why don't you draw the background image *first*?

Then draw the player images, which will therefore appear on top. Does it have to be a sprite? Do you have an alternative way of drawing images, other than as a sprite?

This should stop the background images from covering the player images.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it has to be a sprite, but yes thank you, I will give that background issue a try and see if that doesn't work. Did you by chance happen to see any issue in regards to the player and enemy movements?

Comment: Meant to ask did you happen to see any issues regarding the the player and enemy movements? because before I added that background my players were both able to move left, right, up, & attack. where as to now they can both only move up.